Image and slider dot is out of sync
I just recently completed the basics of HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Now, I am trying to clone the home page of this website: https://www.startech.com.bd/. But I have run into a small problem. The webpage has an image slider, where the image changes every 5 seconds, and there are also three dots representing those three images, respectively.
Here is my code -


const imageResponsive = document.querySelectorAll('[data-image-responsive]');
const dot = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dot]');


let counter = 0;



function changeImage() {

  // First hide all images
  imageResponsive.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none');

  // Show the current image based on the counter value
  imageResponsive[counter].style.display = 'block';

  // First hide all slider dots
  dot.forEach((span) => {
    span.style.background = '#fff';
    span.style.opacity = '0.5';
  });
  // Show the current slider dot based on the counter value
  dot[counter].style.background = '#ef4a23';
  dot[counter].style.opacity = '1';

  // Increment counter and reset if it exceeds the length of the image array
  counter = (counter + 1) % imageResponsive.length;


}



// Start the image change every 5 seconds
setInterval(changeImage, 5000);


// Initially display the first image and the slider dot
imageResponsive[0].style.display = 'block';
dot[0].style.background = '#ef4a23';
dot[0].style.opacity = '1';
.image-responsive-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 990px;
  height: 490px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.image-responsive {
  width: 960px;
  height: 488px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.slider-dot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="image-responsive-div">
  <img class="image-responsive" data-image-responsive src="./resources/images/09-09-24a-v4-(antec-C8-offer-web-banner-design)-982x500.jpg" />
  <img class="image-responsive" data-image-responsive src="./resources/images/express-delivery-girl-receiving-parcel-home-banner-982x500.webp" />
  <img class="image-responsive" data-image-responsive src="./resources/images/queue-banner-home-service-982x500.png" />

  <div class="slider-dot">
    <span class="dot" data-dot></span>
    <span class="dot" data-dot></span>
    <span class="dot" data-dot></span>
  </div>
</div>



But the problem is with the slider. When the website loads, the first image and the first slider load up correctly, but then, when the second image comes, the slider still stays in first place. And when the third image comes, the slider moves to second place. Why is that?
I also tried asking Chatgpt but still did not understand what it said. Anyway, here is its answer: " The issue is happening because your counter is incremented after the images and dots are updated. This causes a delay in the slider dot movement. On the first run, the first image and first dot are shown correctly, but when the counter increments after updating the image for the second time, the dot update is out of sync with the image."
So, can someone explain why the slider and the image are out of sync during the 2nd run?

I believe your images and slider dots are in sync, the problem is just that you show all images at once before the timer is ran for the first time.
When they all stack on top of each other the last one will be on top.
I think what you are seeing is:

3rd image + 1st dot
2nd image + 2nd dot
3rd image + 3rd dot
1st image + 1st dot


Thank you. I was stuck with this problem for two days but finally solved it. And you're correct; it was indeed the actual problem. So what really was happening was that when the webpage was loaded, the 3rd image + 1st dot was shown by default. After 5 seconds, the 1st image + 1st dot was shown, which made it seem like the image was moving, but the dot was not.

The problem is that initially the images don't have display: none so the last one is visible on top of the others.
Make them have display: none to start with by setting that in the style sheet.
This snippet uses images we can see and the dog is the first one so you can check it always shows first


const imageResponsive = document.querySelectorAll('[data-image-responsive]');
const dot = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dot]');


let counter = 0;



function changeImage() {

  // First hide all images
  imageResponsive.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none');

  // Show the current image based on the counter value
  imageResponsive[counter].style.display = 'block';

  // First hide all slider dots
  dot.forEach((span) => {
    span.style.background = '#fff';
    span.style.opacity = '0.5';
  });
  // Show the current slider dot based on the counter value
  dot[counter].style.background = '#ef4a23';
  dot[counter].style.opacity = '1';

  // Increment counter and reset if it exceeds the length of the image array
  counter = (counter + 1) % imageResponsive.length;


}



// Start the image change every 5 seconds
setInterval(changeImage, 5000);


// Initially display the first image and the slider dot

changeImage();
.image-responsive-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 990px;
  height: 490px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.image-responsive {
  width: 960px;
  height: 488px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
}

.slider-dot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="image-responsive-div">
  <img class="image-responsive" data-image-responsive src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/982/500" />
  <img class="image-responsive" data-image-responsive src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/982/500" />
  <img class="image-responsive" data-image-responsive src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/982/500" />

  <div class=" slider-dot ">
    <span class="dot " data-dot></span>
    <span class="dot " data-dot></span>
    <span class="dot " data-dot></span>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you for pointing out the actual problem. And the solution you suggested works correctly, but there is just one issue with it. The counter variable should be set to 1 instead of 0. Since if the counter is set to 0, by default the 1st image + 1st dot loads up. And after 5 seconds, again the 1st image + 1st dot loads up. So it takes 10 seconds instead of 5 seconds to move to the second image.

Yes, silly of me, I meant to call the changeImage to get things started (rather than repeating the various settings). Now corrected.

New css class to show a dot when it is active:
.dot.active {
    background: #ef4a23;
    opacity: 1;
}

Rewritten changeImage function and added startSlider function:
let intervalID;

function changeImage(index = counter) {
    // First hide all images
    imageResponsive.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none');

    // Show the current image based on the counter value
    imageResponsive[index].style.display = 'block';

    // Update dots
    dot.forEach((span) => span.classList.remove('active'));
    dot[index].classList.add('active');

    // If no manual index, increment the counter
    if (index === counter) {
        counter = (counter + 1) % imageResponsive.length;
    }
}

// Start the image change every 5 seconds
function startSlider() {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => changeImage(), 5000);
}

// Initially display the first image and the slider dot
changeImage(0);

// Start the automatic slider
startSlider();

Implementing these changes will fix the errors you were having, you could also look into having the images change when the buttons/dots are clicked on for added functionality, through something such as this:
// Event listener for dots
dot.forEach((span, index) => {
    span.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Clear the auto slider when a dot is clicked
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        counter = index;  // Set the counter to the clicked dot index
        changeImage(index);  // Change image to the one corresponding to the clicked dot
        startSlider();  // Restart auto slider after manual change
    });
});


Thank you for replying. I was actually looking forward to adding the click functionality and will use your solution.
